# Naive Bayes spam classifier improvements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you please have a look at our naive bayes model. We look at a corpus of emails where an email is either spam or not. To classifiy we naively assume a bag of words and estimate prior probabilities through maximum likelihood. The model defintion can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Probabilistic_model):

Specifically we are interested to understand if:

1. Usage of `self` variables is fine or e.g. if methods should return things functionally instead of changing inplace.
2. Splitting of methods is good practice or if it should be more condensed (i.e., less methods, bigger methods)
3. Any unpythonic things or things you find hard to understand.
4. I am aware lambda functions are supposedly no good practice but for the purpose I found them convenient. But please comment on that as well. I could declare a local function instead of using lambda.

**Model**:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
import os
import pickle
import operator
import math

class NaiveBayes:

    def __init__(self, mode):

        # Sets file path arguments depending on mode of model usage
        self.mode = mode
        self.set_arguments()

        # Variables to save frequencies to
        self.freq_word_given_class = self.create_class_defaultdict()
        self.freq_word = defaultdict(int)
        self.freq_class = defaultdict(int)

        # Variables to save ML estimators to
        self.prob_word_given_class = self.create_class_defaultdict()
        self.prob_word = defaultdict(int)
        self.prob_class = defaultdict(int)

        # Variables needed for backoff smoothing
        self.rel_freq_word_given_class = self.create_class_defaultdict()
        self.prob_word_given_class_backoff = self.create_class_defaultdict()

    def predict(self):
        """
        Doc string
        """
        for file, target in self.get_files():
            with open(f"{os.getcwd()}/test/{target}/{file}", encoding="latin-1") as f:
                email = f.read().split()

                # Get probability score for each class
                # Operating in log space because probabilities get very small
                log_score = dict()
                for _class in self.classes:
                    log_prob_class = math.log(self.prob_class[_class])
                    log_prob_doc = 0
                    for word in email:
                        prob_given_class = self.prob_word_given_class_backoff[_class]
                        # It would be bad to assume unknown have 0 probability. That would likely
                        # misclassify documents simply because a word wasnt seen during data.
                        if word not in prob_given_class: continue  # Just skip
                        log_prob_doc += math.log(prob_given_class[word])
                    log_score[_class] = log_prob_class + log_prob_doc

                # Save the prediction
                prediction = max(log_score.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
                self.save_score(target, prediction)

                print(file + "\t" + prediction + "\n")

        # Show result
        self.show_score(which="accuracy")

    def save_score(self, target, prediction):
        """Increase counter[0] when classified correctly else increase counter[1] by 1."""
        self.counter[target==prediction] += 1

    def show_score(self, which):
        """
        Doc string
        """
        if which == "accuracy":
            accuracy = self.counter[0]/(self.counter[0] + self.counter[1])
            print("Accuracy: " + str(accuracy))
            # print(self.counter)

    def fit(self):
        """Estimates probabilities given the frequencies. Then apply backoff smoothing."""

        if self.mode == "test":
            params = self.load_parameters()
            self.prob_word_given_class = params["prob_word_given_class"]
            self.prob_word = params["prob_word"]
            self.prob_class = params["prob_class"]
            self.prob_word_given_class_backoff = params["prob_word_given_class_backoff"]
            self.counter = [0,0]  # Preliminary counter to count how many times classification is right

        elif self.mode == "train":
            self.count_frequencies()
            self.estimate_parameters()
            self.smooth_parameters()

    def count_frequencies(self):
        """Count word frequencies, word frequencies given the class and class frequencies."""
        for file, _class in self.get_files():
            file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"train", _class, file)
            with open(file, encoding="latin-1") as f:
                email = f.read().split()
                # Count emails frequencies
                self.freq_class[_class] += 1
                for word in email:
                    self.freq_word_given_class[_class][word] += 1
                    self.freq_word[word] += 1

    def estimate_parameters(self):
        """Estimates the model parameters given the words frequencies."""

        for _class in self.classes:
            # Estimate probability of word given class: p(w|c) = f(w,c) / sum_w' f(w',c)
            frequencies = self.freq_word_given_class[_class]
            _sum = sum(frequencies.values())
            self.prob_word_given_class[_class] = {k: v/_sum for k, v in frequencies.items()}

        # Estimate probability of word: p(w) = f(w) / sum(f(w')
        _sum = sum(self.freq_word.values())
        self.prob_word = {k: v/_sum for k, v in self.freq_word.items()}

        # Estimate probability of class: p(c) = f(c) / sum(f(c'))
        _sum = sum(self.freq_class.values())
        self.prob_class = {k: v/_sum for k, v in self.freq_class.items()}

    def smooth_parameters(self):
            """Smoothes the model by Kneser-Ney smoothing."""

            # Calulcate discount factor delta after Kneser/Essen/Ney
            n = lambda x: sum(list(self.freq_word_given_class[_class].values()).count(x) for _class in self.classes)
            delta = n(1) / (n(1) + 2*n(2))

            # Calulcate relativ frequencies of word given class: r(w|c) = max(0, f(w,c) - delta) / sum_w' f(w',c)
            for _class in self.classes:
                _sum = sum(self.freq_word_given_class[_class].values())  # Sum_w' f(w',c)
                self.rel_freq_word_given_class[_class] = {k: max(0, v - delta) / _sum
                                                          for k, v in self.freq_word_given_class[_class].items()}

            # Dynamically calculate backoff factor alpha
            alpha = lambda _class: 1 - sum(self.rel_freq_word_given_class[_class].values())

            # Calulcate discount probability: p(w|c) = r(w|c) + alpha(c)p(w)
            for _class in self.classes:
                _alpha, rel_word_freq = alpha(_class), self.rel_freq_word_given_class[_class]
                self.prob_word_given_class_backoff[_class]= {k: rel_word_freq[k] + _alpha * self.prob_word[k]
                                                              for k, v in self.prob_word_given_class[_class].items()}

    def set_arguments(self):
        """Sets variables depending on the mode of model usage."""

        self.paramfile = sys.argv[1]
        self.data_dir = sys.argv[2]
        # In train mode parameters are passed vice versa
        if self.mode == "train":
            self.data_dir, self.paramfile = self.paramfile, self.data_dir
        self.classes = next(os.walk(self.data_dir))[1]

    def create_class_defaultdict(self):
        """Helper method to create defaultdict of classes."""
        return {_class: defaultdict(int) for _class in self.classes}

    def get_files(self):
        """
        Generator object that returns the next file and its
        corresponding class every time next() is called.
        """
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.data_dir):
            for _class in self.classes:
                if root.endswith(_class):
                    for file in files:
                        yield file, _class

    def load_parameters(self):
        with open(self.paramfile, 'rb') as handle:
            return pickle.load(handle)

    def save_parameters(self):
        params = {"prob_word": self.prob_word,
                  "prob_class": self.prob_class,
                  "prob_word_given_class": self.prob_word_given_class,
                  "prob_word_given_class_backoff": self.prob_word_given_class_backoff}
        with open(f"{self.paramfile}.pickle", 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(params, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**Training call:**

```
from model import NaiveBayes
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert len(sys.argv) == 3, "Call script as $ python3 test.py paramfile mail-dir"
    nb = NaiveBayes(mode="train")
    nb.fit()
    nb.save_parameters()
```

**Test/inference call:**

```
from model import NaiveBayes
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert len(sys.argv) == 3, "Call script as python3 train.py train-dir paramfile"
    nb = NaiveBayes(mode="test")
    nb.fit()
    nb.predict()
```